# Was the custom of covering Kaaba in black cloth adopted during the Fatimid era?

Tags: islam

[This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2117/3487) answer to [*Why is the Kaaba covered in black cloth?*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2048/3487) states that the black cloth for [Kaaba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba) a tradition which is continued to-date was adopted by the [Fatimids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimid_Caliphate).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; after the Fatmids.

Wikipedia to the rescue

> Later on, Al-Nasir the Abbasid draped the Kaaba with green, both Al Nasir and Al-Ma'mun disagreed on the frequent color changes and switched to black, and black it remains to this day. *[Kiswah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiswah)*

Al Nasir ruled from 1180; the [Fatmids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimid_Caliphate) appear to be 909 to 1171.